# Calling full trust assembly from a low trust assembly with AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers 'proxy' assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

If you have a third party assembly that requires full trust for say a logging operation (This assembly does not have `AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers`).

You use this assembly through a custom assembly with `AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers` then deploy it to the GAC.

How can you use your custom assembly from low trust code when it's dependency (third party assembly) issues security demands?

Note: Context is sharepoint.

Comment: Not sure what the question is as you've explained how to do so (APTCA assembly in the GAC which asserts demands).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I still see security exceptions when the custom assembily (in the gac) calls out to the SharePoint assembily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best guess : missing assert for security demands. Check out [MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288469%28v=VS.71%29.aspx#vcwlksecuritytutorialsuppressingsecurity) to get started. And [SecurityPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z15f82t9.aspx) class for Assert method.